# Изменить значение ячейки в Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
>>df
  A  B  C  D
E 0  0  0  0
F 0  0  0  0
G 0  0  0  0
H 0  0  0  0
```

Необходимо изменить ячейку `df[A][E]`.
Применение `df[A][E] = 2`
приводит к предупреждению.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [`DataFrame.loc[<index_slice>, <column_slice>]`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
In [7]: df.loc['E','A'] = 111

In [8]: df
Out[8]:
     A  B  C  D
E  111  0  0  0
F    0  0  0  0
G    0  0  0  0
H    0  0  0  0
```

или [`DataFrame.at[...]`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.at.html):

```
In [10]: df.at['E', 'A'] = 222

In [11]: df
Out[11]:
     A  B  C  D
E  222  0  0  0
F    0  0  0  0
G    0  0  0  0
H    0  0  0  0
```